# Proving the existence of simple graph that has two vertices of same degree while other vertices degrees are different.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for any $n>1$ there is a simple graph of order $n$, which has exactly two vertices of the same degree, and the rest of the vertices have degrees that are different from one another.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: Well I made a few simple cases for myself to grasp, but I find it hard to generalize it.

Comment: Duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719363)

Answer (score 2):

For $n=2$ consider two isolated vertices.

Inductively define a sequence of graphs in the following way:

If $G_n$ is connected, define $G_{n+1}$ to be $G_n$ plus some isolated vertex. 
If $G_n$ is not connected, define $G_{n+1}$ to be the graph obtained from $G_n$ by attaching a single new vertex to every vertex in $G_n$.

I leave it to you to argue, why this sequence of graphs satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Label the vertices $1,\dots, n$ and connect $i$ and $j$ if and only if $i+j\geq n$. It is clear $n$ and $n-1$ have the same degrees, and vertex $i$ has degree $i+2$ for $i<n-1$